# User resurrecting old questions with the same answer - what is the best approach?

Tags: discussion, spam

Suppose there is old question (e.g. asked over year ago) and someone post new answer with some new data or different solution. So far so good.

But.. suppose that user post the **same answer** for 14 different questions that are similar in their context though not duplicates?

The answer might be helpful, there is no direct link anywhere but still.... what's your opinion on the correct approach when you see such thing?

I saw earlier such thing happen for something in JavaScript in SO, and flagged one of the 14 pointing on the fact he posted the same answer 14 times and now I can't find the answers anymore.. probably got deleted?

Comment: It was someone posting to get traffic to their website; it's been taken care of. :)

Comment: @Rob thanks that's was my assumption as well... but what if he would have posted it only once?

Comment: If it doesn't address the question, mark it as spam; if it does it's probably fine. Usually in situations like this, the person sells a product to do X, so they search SO for "X" and post an identical answer on every matching question, so a majority of the answers don't even address the question

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> It was someone posting to get traffic
>   to their website; it's been taken care
>   of. :) – Robert Harvey♦